How does "On the ground!" really fits here?
With weapons in her hand, Nebula speaks to Adam Warlock, who
is trying to catch Rocket:

Nebula: On the ground!

According to the dictionary,
"On the ground!" means "among the general public"
How does "On the ground!" really fits here?
Source: Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3 (2023)

Hard to tell from context, but it looks like what Nebula means is Get on the ground! or maybe Lie down on the ground!

It's a terse form of command that omits a verb, like a soldier's curt command to a prisoner: "On your knees!" or "Hands in the air!"

As with many idioms you should also consider if the literal meaning fits the context.
The idiom is used, for example, in news reports, and refers to a report that comes directly from the location that something happened, rather than how it appears from a distance. It contrasts the view that a reporter gets by standing on the ground compared to the view from an airplane flying overhead.
But on the ground can also be literal. Dictionaries don't normally list literal senses of idioms, they are considered to be obvious. Since in the movie the characters do a lot of flying about, and being shot at by laser guns etc, it seems most likely that "on the ground" just means "not flying around" or "lie down to avoid the gunfire".  It should probably be understood, in context as an instruction  "lie on the ground" or "stand on the ground".
